# Store In localStorage is showing 2 values as debugger and Undefined

Tags: javascript, local-storage

> I am Buildig Normal HTML And Materialize Css And Javascript.
>   When i am storing tasks in my localStorage it was Storing on localStorage But it was Printing Two Values one is My Tasks and These is All Of my code and Please Tell the way i can solve this debugger..
>   Another Showing As Debugger undefined..
>
> ```
> What is Debugger and undefined and Why It was Showing ..?
> Please View The Code..!
> ```
>
> in Local Storage I am Getting Like
>
> ```
> Key     Value
> tasks   ["Walk the Dog"]
> debugger undefined
> Thank You
> ```

```
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks');


loadEventListeners();

function loadEventListeners(){
    form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
    taskList.addEventListener('click', removeTask);
    clearBtn.addEventListener('click',clearTasks);
    filter.addEventListener('keyup', filterLi)
}

function addTask(e){
    if(taskInput.value ===''){
        alert('Please Add Task');
    } else {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'collection-item';
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
    link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>'
    li.appendChild(link);
    taskList.appendChild(li);
    storeTaskInLocalStorage(taskInput.value);
    e.preventDefault();

    taskInput.value="";
```

}
    }

```
function storeTaskInLocalStorage(task){
    let tasks;
    if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null){
        tasks = [];
    } else{
        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    }
    tasks.push(task);
    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}

function removeTask(e){
    if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')){
        e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
}

function clearTasks(){
    while(taskList.firstChild){
        taskList.removeChild(taskList.firstChild)
    }
}

function filterLi(e){
    const filterText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    document.querySelectorAll('.collection-item').forEach(function(task){
        const litem = task.firstChild.textContent;
        if(litem.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText) != -1){
            task.style.display = 'block'
        } else{
            task.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the key as you are not adding it though your app. I've noticed something similar when using sockets.io but you are not using sockets.io.

If it bothers you, you can remove that key yourself.

```js
// Run this in your console 
localStorage.removeItem('debugger');
```

Comment: It's hard to tell where it's coming from. Your code doesn't add any key with name 'debugger'. Although I noticed that you are just showing an alert when adding a task in addTask function when the input is empty and still continuing to add that empty string anyway?

Comment: Yes it was adding empt task even i am just press add Task it was adding like empy li :( i am not understand. Can you help that please

Comment: Just wrap the code after if statement in addTask function in the ```else { // all the logic to manipulate Dom and adding item to localStorage } ```

Comment: Bro wait Should i meet you any other farms like facebook

Comment: Dude ani Aggarwal thanks for assist i get it that e.preventDefault(); Causing problem, i learned it was always in last it works perfect and  i am not getting one thing is there is value in taskInput or not it was taking as li and puting in dom that only problem i am getting now