# Without Adding any value li creating automatically

Tags: javascript, dom

I am try to create a normal ui, for that i am adding some tasks,
in those i am set taskInput without any value as alert('Please add task');
but it even without adding any value in taskInput it was showing as list item in Dom..

in below is my simple form even if we put nothing in taskInput it will alert add task but it was again doing an empt list item.

```
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks');

function loadEventListeners(){
    form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
    taskList.addEventListener('click', removeTask);
    clearBtn.addEventListener('click',clearTasks);
    filter.addEventListener('keyup', filterLi)
}

function addTask(e){
    if(taskInput.value ===''){
        alert('Please Add Task');
    }
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'collection-item';
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
    link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>'
    li.appendChild(link);
    taskList.appendChild(li);
    taskInput.value="";
    e.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store In localStorage is showing 2 values as debugger and Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839122/store-in-localstorage-is-showing-2-values-as-debugger-and-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a list item if the value is empty, you should return after the alert:

```
if(taskInput.value ===''){
    alert('Please Add Task');
    return;
}
```

Otherwise, it'll alert, and then proceed to create an empty list item.